# Doctrine2: Browser freezes using Many-To-Many self-referencing

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have one PHP model class named Elements and it has a Many-To-Many self-referencing. I have created a ManyToMany relation like that:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /**
  * Elements
  *
  * @ORM\Table()
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Evalfor\GescompevalBundle\Entity\ElementsRepository")
  */
class Elements
{
  // Constants
  const COMPETENCE = "competence";
  const RESULT = "result";

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

// ... More attributes ...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Elements", mappedBy="myElements")
 **/
private $elementsWithMe;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Elements", inversedBy="elementsWithMe")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="connected_elements"),
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="element_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="connected_element_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
private $myElements;


/**
 * Construct
 *
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->elementsWithMe = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->myElements = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addElement(Elements $element)
{
    $element->addElement($this);
    $this->myElements[] = $element;

    return $this;
}

public function getElements(){
    return $this->myElements;
}

// ... More methods ...
}
```

Besides, I have an empty repository for Elements:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class ElementsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

And finally, I have an Element Controller:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Evalfor\GescompevalBundle\Entity\Elements;
use Evalfor\GescompevalBundle\Form\ElementsType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ElementsController extends Controller
{
    // ... Some methods ...

    public function updateAction($type)
    {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $elements_all = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EvalforGescompevalBundle:Elements')->findAll();
      print_r($elements_all); exit;

     // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the browser freezes when I call the findAll() method (same for other methods like that), but if I delete all ManyToMany references in Elements class it works perfectly.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there's an Element that has itself in myElements. Maybe this causes an infine loop? Is there any error message?

Comment: There aren't any relations in the DB or the application, only a couple of Elements. No error message, only freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this updating the action of the controller. I changed the model a couple of days ago, so I suppose that some old methods or objets are still there. If anyone has the same problem, I recommend cheking the entire controller, not only the code line that causes the error.

Comment: Ok, I'm sure now, the problem appears because print_r(), for some reason, it can't show the datas.